# Cognitive services - Describe image Azure Microsoft Flow

Tags: azure, image-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, power-automate

When I try to connect the Action "Computer Vision API - Describe Image" in Flow with my Cognitive service in Azure I get an Error as follow:

{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide
 a valid key for an active subscription." }

I copied the keys from the Azure portal -> Cognitive service into Flow, but somehow I get this error message. Any idea's?

[Microsoft Flow Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zDBG.png)

[Azure Cognitive services Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOa5T.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Flow service only uses the West US Cognitive endpoint, but it looks like you created your Computer Vision API account in West Europe.  Try creating a new Computer Vision API in the West US region.

Comment: Thanks! Will try that.

Comment: Yes it works! Awesome stuff. Could it be at this moment that the describe image is not able to access an imange from a SharePoint library? When I Google an image and use that it works but if I use a SharePoint library URL it can't access the image.

Comment: I assume your Sharepoint site is either not publicly available or requires authentication, which Flow won't be able to access.